# RadioButton change jquery method not working after DOM changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am changing html of the radiobutton (name of the radiobutton is the same) through ajax based on logice (Rates, duration changes). Before DOM changes `change(function(e)` method works perfect, once it DOM changes `change(function(e)`not working. What I'm doing wrong?

```
<tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="membershipTerm" checked="@yr1"  value="@membership.Year1RateCode">
        </td>
        <td>1 Year  Membership (@startDate to @Convert.ToDateTime(membership.CycleEndDate).Date.ToString("MMM yyyy"))</td>
        <td>1 Year</td>
        <td style="text-align: right">$<span class="membershipPrice">@membership.Year1Price</span> USD</td>
    </tr>


  $('input[type=radio][name=membershipTerm]').change(function(e) {
            var price = $(e.target).parent().parent().find("span").text();
            membershipData.updatemembershipPrice(price);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use event delegation for attaching events to dynamically added DOM elements:

```
$(document).on('change','input[type=radio][name=membershipTerm]',function(e) {
        var price = $(e.target).parent().parent().find("span").text();
        membershipData.updatemembershipPrice(price);
```